# Regex to split multiline text in C#

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I'm trying to build a regex to split the message archive sent by email from WhatsApp.

Example:

```
23.02.16, 11:01 - Herr Paul Muster: han vpn verbindig zu ufgmacht und die kappt ja sinternet
23.02.16, 11:01 - Herr Paul Muster: jetzt channi mi nümme verbinde 
23.02.16, 11:10 - Herr Paul Muster: merci
25.02.16, 09:09 - Herr Peter Nachname: Bin i 15min im office
07.03.16, 09:29 - Herr Peter Nachname: Da ich weiss dases eh nid kommuniziert wird, schribis eu au. Ich wird hüt dihei blibe, han migräneartigi grindschmerze...lg
07.03.16, 09:30 - Markus: Ok, danke für d'info (und dini hellseherische fähigkeite)
Gueti besserig
04.04.16, 09:24 - Herr Peter Nachname: Bi grad im office 
13.04.16, 19:00 - Herr Paul Muster: mir sind usem büro usgschlosse 
13.04.16, 19:00 - Herr Paul Muster: händ meeting gah 
und all händ dä schlüssel 
im büro 
13.04.16, 19:08 - Herr Peter Nachname: Lol 
13.04.16, 19:12 - Herr Paul Muster: du bisch eh grossi hilf  bisch nid per zuefall ih dä nöchi?
```

At the end of each line is a linefeed (\n) in place.
At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
new Regex(@"([\d]{2}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}, [\d]{2}:[\d]{2})[\s]-[\s](.*):[\s](.*)");
```

The first group of the `MatchCollection` contains the date, the second part the sender.
The third group contains only the message text until the end of the line.
But I want to get the whole message, including the line feeds or whatever till the next match of the `datepart`.

I checked several forums and QA-pages but I couldn't find any solution for my problem. So maybe someone here can give me a hint to the right solution for my problem.

Comment: If you let it cross `\n`, the `.*` will be greedy and eat up the rest of the entire email. How would you prefer to indicate a new `datepart`? What if someone had put a date in their message?

Comment: Just a quick shot: https://regex101.com/r/cN2rC4/1

Comment: @4castle: A new datepart is identified by the first group - i don't think that someone enters a date in the same format into the message and also followed by a "space, dash, space" and so on.
So this question can be ignored

Comment: @SebastianProske: Thanks for your tip - on the linked homepage everything works fine - but if try to add the same regex pattern to my code I recieve an error, that "\R" is not valid

Comment: @MarkusH. you can replace it by `\n`, if your linebreak is LF, or by `\r\n` if it is CLRF

Comment: @SebastianProske: Thanks for the hint - it works great this way.
I tried before replacing the \R with \n but somehow it dind't work.
But know it worked using the following expression
`new Regex(@"(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s(.*?):\s((?:.+|\n(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2}))+)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a .NET-only solution:

```
new Regex(@"(^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s([^:]*):\s(.*?)$",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

The Multiline option allows `^` and `$` to match at line boundaries, Singleline allows `.` to match newlines, and RightToLeft causes matching to proceed backwards from the end of the string.

The non-greedy `(.*?)` causes it to stop matching at the first occurrence (or next occurrence, going backward) of a `Date, Time - Name:` sequence, so it matches only one line at a time.  The matches will be in reverse order, but the groups won't.

If that feels too much like black magic, you can use this instead:

```
new Regex(@"(^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s([^:]*):\s((?:(?!^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2},).)*)$",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

`(?:(?!^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2},).)*` matches zero or more characters (including newlines, because of the Singleline option), until the next character is the beginning of a date at the beginning of a line (or until there are no more characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround with first Regex.Replace():

```
string pattern =  @"(.)$\n(\D\D[^.]\D\D[^.]\D\D)";
string input = ""; // Your multiline input
string replacement = "$1$2";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Which will give you:

```
23.02.16, 11:01 - Herr Paul Muster: han vpn verbindig zu ufgmacht und die kappt ja sinternet
23.02.16, 11:01 - Herr Paul Muster: jetzt channi mi nümme verbinde 
23.02.16, 11:10 - Herr Paul Muster: merci
25.02.16, 09:09 - Herr Peter Nachname: Bin i 15min im office 07.03.16, 09:29 - Herr Peter Nachname: Da ich weiss dases eh nid kommuniziert wird, schribis eu au. Ich wird hüt dihei blibe, han migräneartigi grindschmerze...lg 07.03.16, 09:30 - Markus: Ok, danke für d'info (und dini hellseherische fähigkeite)Gueti besserig
04.04.16, 09:24 - Herr Peter Nachname: Bi grad im office 
13.04.16, 19:00 - Herr Paul Muster: mir sind usem büro usgschlosse  13.04.16, 19:00 - Herr Paul Muster: händ meeting gah und all händ dä schlüssel im büro 
13.04.16, 19:08 - Herr Peter Nachname: Lol 
13.04.16, 19:12 - Herr Paul Muster: du bisch eh grossi hilf  bisch nid per zuefall ih dä nöchi?
```

Then you can apply your regex `new Regex(@"([\d]{2}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}, [\d]{2}:[\d]{2})[\s]-[\s](.*):[\s](.*)");` to have your groups.

---

#### Limits:

If your new line start with a date but is not a new entry, it will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.
Maybe this is caused by copying the example content to and from this webpage. In the "real" application I read a text file with only a \n at the end of each line. If copied from here it maybe adds another kind of linebreak in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string pattern = @"([\d]{2}.[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}, [\d]{2}:[\d]{2})[\s]-[\s](.*?):[\s](.*?)(?=\r\n\d|\z)";

var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Note a couple of lazy quantifiers.

At the end, we check the presence of the digit that is in the beginning of the next sentence or the end of the file.

Singleline option need to point captured any character, including newlines.

Comment: Using your pattern and option I just recieve a final match of 3 groups.
Group 1 contains the first datepart, Group 2 contains the whole text to the first double point (on line 3) and Group 3 contains the whole rest of the input text

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all inputs

I was able to solve my problem with the input from Sebasian Proske using the following regex pattern:

`new Regex(@"(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2})\s-\s(.*?):\s((?:.+|\n(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2}))+)");`